# Simple user query with orderBy not working

Tags: users, query, elementquery

**Craft 3.3.13**

This query does not order users correctly.

```
{% set users = craft.users.groupId(3).orderBy('lastName asc') %}
```

Bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just stumbled across this issue myself, I found that in the orderBy parameter that while 'lastName' didn't order correctly, 'lastname' did.

Comment: Weird - but it works!

Comment: Ahh... probably the database is configured to use a case-sensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a simple test on a fresh install of the latest Craft with 3 users in a user group using this code and the output was what I'd expect:

```
{% set users = craft.users.groupId(1).orderBy('lastName asc') %}

<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.lastName }}, {{ user.firstName }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Gives:

- Aardvark, Adam
- Meadows, Marc
- Zimmerman, Bob

Comment: Weird. I checked it pretty thoroughly before giving up.

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL by chance?

Comment: No, MySQL is the DB.

Comment: in that case, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯